# Loading static copy content from a JSON file into a Vue web site?

Tags: json, vue.js

I'd like to use a .json file to load all of my content copy into my new Vue web site.

I'd like to import a file:

```
import Copy from '@/content/home.json';
```

Then have the content accessible to my template. My preference is to have the content file loaded in the page, then pass relevant data into components as props.

I hope that makes sense, my searches have pulled up all sorts of JSON/data related solutions but they all seem over-engineered for what I want.

If you need more info I will happily provide.

Comment: This is actually the correct way for using a JSON file. So what actually is not working for you?

Comment: I just don't know what to access. Examples I've seen have you iterating through the object or assigning data to the Vue object - I just feel that what I want to do should be really simple. Is it just a case of {{object_root.path.value}} in the template? I'm fairly new to this sort of dev (in case that wasn't obvious).

Comment: I'm not on my computer right now, I'll have a play later with what I've seen today and hopefully get somewhere with it.